# Configure line highlighting length limits for git commit in vim

Tags: git, vim

I'm quite new to vim. But one thing I keep reading is that it is possible to have color highlighting if you exceed the character limit in your commit messages (summary + message) with vim.

I've searched up and down but can't to figure out how to configure it.

Comment: Note that `textwidth` is already set to `72` and autoformatting enabled in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` so it is not easy to go over out of the box.

Comment: But how would I activate the autoformatting. I'm quite new to vim, so your response is somewhat cryptic (it's probably right, though - and I don't want to sound unappreciative). But maybe you could put it in laymans terms?

Comment: A default vim install *should* automatically activate the checking when editing a file named `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, as will happen when you use `vim` as your chosen editor and run `git commit`. In other words, you should not need to *configure* anything at all: it should work "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

There's `colorcolumn` option (see `:h 'cc'`). Assuming you have already set `:h 'textwidth'` properly, you can use relative value for `colorcolumn`:

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim

```
setlocal textwidth=79
setlocal colorcolumn=+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the syntax file at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/gitcommit.vim`, where the commit message is highlighted.

```
syn match   gitcommitSummary    "^.*\%<51v." contained containedin=gitcommitFirstLine nextgroup=gitcommitOverflow contains=@Spell
" hi def link gitcommitOverflow     Error
```

You can add the two lines to your local after/syntax file like `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/gitcommit.vim`. Then you can adjust the length limit (`51`) and highlighting (`Error`) as you like.

```
syn match   gitcommitSummary    "^.*\%<61v." contained containedin=gitcommitFirstLine nextgroup=gitcommitOverflow contains=@Spell
hi def link gitcommitOverflow       Underlined
```